# How do I add some text onto the divider between rows?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, interface-design

Example (with "OR" as text):

[image: Example (with "OR" as text)]

The idea is that on collapse of columns—i.e.: view on mobile sized-screen—it will appear betwixt `submit` and `Click me`.

**How do I add some text onto the divider between rows?**

Comment: And your current html would be..?

Comment: [Current HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/CwqmD/) (JSfiddle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a `.span` between your two forms ?

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span5">
            form 1
        </div>
        <div class="span2">OR</div>
        <div class="span5">
            form 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/QygFS/)

Comment: Thanks, not exactly what I was looking for, but seems to work better. I should've thought of this first :P

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.wrapper{
width:900px;
margin:0 auto;}

.left{
min-height:300px;
width:400px;
background-color:#9F0;
float:left;} 

.right{
min-height:300px;
width:400px;
background-color:#9F0;
float:right;}

.mid{
padding-top:150px;
padding-left:40px;
min-height:150px;
width:60px;
float:left;
background-color:#C00;}
</style>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">SUBMIT CONTENT HERE</div>
    <div class="mid">OR</div>
    <div class="right">CLICK ME CONTENT HERE</div>   
</div>
```

I think this can help you. now you can style it if you want to add vertical bar on `mid` you can add that bar as a background image 
then you can style it or add any DIV tags to it Its your wish.. ;)